# How to increase cpu usage

Tags: fortran

For my Thesis I want to write fortran program. I have a K53-Sm ASUS laptop with core i7 and 8Gig ram. When I run my program my CPU usage is 13%.
How can I increase my CPU usage to 100% on Ubuntu 13.04 and all of 8 cores CPU cores active?

Comment: what do you mean, do you want your CPU to be used at maximum all the time for testing ? or do you want ubuntu to use all the ressources all the time ? becaus e linux is design to use only the ressource it needs, so it meens your computer is 40% too powerfull

Comment: Show us your code, is your code supposed to use 100% of your CPU? It is written with threats in mind? If it's not is possible that you need to rewrite it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it relates to the writing of multi-threaded FORTRAN code rather than anything specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the stress tool (to impose load on and stress test systems) available from the repos:

```
sudo apt-get install stress
```

Alternatively you could also try:

```
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~manjo/checkbox/stress-test/view/head:/checkbox-old/scripts/cpustress.c
```

It will stress CPU integer and floating point paths. It also execises CPU path that deals with data and text cache misses.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a power-management tool like [TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html). That has a function which is turbo mode. The latter will give you all your CPU horsepower.

If you really want to use every single CPU to 100% you will probably also have to do some multi-threading programming, viz. create different simultaneous threads to do the computations at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to implement a message passing interface so that the CPU's can communicate.The compiler will vectorize loops (enable Software parallelization but this is only basic level of parallelism,to make full use of your CPU you will have to implement a MPI.

Note that this will require you to restructure the program for this purpose.

You may also look into co-fortran.