# Increase processor utilisation of one application/program

Tags: ram, cpu

I use [ClustalX](http://www.clustal.org/clustal2/) to align few unusually big sequences on my home desktop, this takes more than a week to complete and runs well below the maximum capacity of the machine.

The `top | grep clustalx` gives the following output

> 5985 @username    0 -20 1971048 105428   9012 R  **99.9  2.7**   5829:27 clustalx

It shows the CPU usage is ~100 and the memory usage ~3% RAM. But the system monitor says otherwise,

[image: CPU Usage history and Memory history]

There are 2 CPU cores running at maximum in the picture, that's because I am using firefox and the system monitor, otherwise its just one. I have also set the priority of clustalx to `Very high` and yet, there is no considerable improvement I could see.

What more should I do that it utilises more CPU and RAM. Any suggestions would be useful.

Load average ~2.7(when I'm using other programs also)

I have seen the following post related to this, but they don't answer my question:

[How to increase cpu usage [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/q/432675/117406)

**System specifications:**
Ubuntu 64 bit 14.04 LTS on 154GB HDD partition, 4GB RAM, Intel Core i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4 processor, and 10 GB swap.

**Program Spcification:**
ClustalX for linux - Used in biological sequence alignment.

To determine if my program is 32/64 bit, I used

`find /usr/bin/clustalx`

> /usr/bin/clustalx: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),...

Comment: It seems probable that your program is single threaded, meaning it can only utilize one CPU at a time. So you are getting all you can out of it.

Comment: @DougSmythies how do I find it? Other programs I use(python, shell scripts) use all the resources available...

Comment: Andrew, you'd better ask this question to Clustal developers. Generally speaking, there are no ways to force a program to use more resources without modifying the program itself.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, that would be my last resort, wanted to know if anything else is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Easy: run your program as many times as you have cores...

I do the same to transcode video in multiple formats: not all video-encoders are multi-core/multi-CPU-aware, so I run a video-encore for one resolution on one core and the other one (with different command-line parameters) on another core.

**Low-quality reviewers:** some complex problems have exceedingly simple solutions.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, just curious though when sometime when I click on `firefox`'s icon more than once, it throws an error saying 'an instance already running...'. Wouldn't that happen here again?

Comment: Firefox is a multi-windowed application that is specifically programmed not to run more then once.  Other examples are LibreOffice, GIMP, ...  Most applications like bash, gedit, avconv aren't multi-windowed and can be run multiple times, so I can't tell you specifically for the application you're running.  Just test it out. And if it works, don't forget to  click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I did try it, first one with an `&` in the end and second one without it. There were two different pids assigned to it, all the resources were put to use though! I still had to wait the same time as a single instance running with one core utilisation. I guess they aren't cooperating, or at least in my case.

Comment: No, off course they don't cooperate, you have to have each of them working on different sequences... ** ;-)**  Sorry for being unclear.  Answer edited.

Comment: ClustalX is used to group similar regions in a pool of many sequences, I need to run them simultaneously.

Comment: @Andrew: can you drop by the [AU Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping me there?  We need to talk directly as here we're talking next to each other. My TZ is UTC+1.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

https://www.biostars.org/p/44231/

it sounds like clustalx will only the one core, and you need to use clustal omega or mafft.

Comment: I have tried using MAFFT, it doesn't use up all the resources either! I'll try out Clustal Omega and get back @user3113723.

Comment: I just found out that clustal omega doesn't align genes, it only aligns proteins.